# How to fit Qt application in phone window?

Tags: qt

How to fit Qt application in phone window? When app is being designed it fixes the size of controls like combobox, calendar etc. When I run in emulator they are squeezed but, I want them to resize n fit in window as per the size of window.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `showFullScreen` instead of `show`.